# Selecting and targeting matplotlib backends

Tags: python, matplotlib

Are there general rules or best practices for selecting and targeting matplotlib backends? Specifically

1. is there a backend I should select for non-interactive mode when (a) running plotting code from others or (b) in running or writing my own to get the best results and to avoid any quirks or bugs; and
2. is there a backend I should target or assume (and test and debug with) if I want my code to be as portable as possible and to work in both interactive and non interactive modes?

Comment: AFAIK, 'agg' seems work very well for (1), while (2) is made difficult by quirks (e.g. warnings from `tight_layout` in some backends).